Designing fancy buttons in JavaFX without HTML
I am working on a project in JavaFX to make a fancy UI (using CSS and FXML) and I stumbled across the code below for a fancy button that I want to use. I copied the CSS code and wrote it in a CSS file in IntelliJ. Then I went into a scene builder, applied the CSS file as a stylesheet for my button and it didn't work. I later saw that on the site where I copied the code, there was also a HTML code which seemed necessary to implement as well. The problem is I have no knowledge about HTML whatsoever and I would like to only stick to CSS for the time being. What should I do with the HTML file and how should I implement it so the scene builder properly can read the stylesheet. It works when I copy CSS code that doesn't have any extra HTML code. I am using Windows.
Here is the CSS code:
html,
body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100vh;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   background: #000;
}

.glow-on-hover {
   width: 220px;
   height: 50px;
   border: none;
   outline: none;
   color: #fff;
   background: #111;
   cursor: pointer;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 0;
   border-radius: 10px;
}

.glow-on-hover:before {
   content: '';
   background: linear-gradient(45deg, #ff0000, #ff7300, #fffb00, #48ff00, #00ffd5, 
               #002bff, #7a00ff, #ff00c8, #ff0000);
   position: absolute;
   top: -2px;
   left:-2px;
   background-size: 400%;
   z-index: -1;
   filter: blur(5px);
   width: calc(100% + 4px);
   height: calc(100% + 4px);
   animation: glowing 20s linear infinite;
   opacity: 0;
   transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
   border-radius: 10px;
}

.glow-on-hover:active {
   color: #000
}

.glow-on-hover:active:after {
   background: transparent;
}

.glow-on-hover:hover:before {
   opacity: 1;
}

.glow-on-hover:after {
   z-index: -1;
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background: #111;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   border-radius: 10px;
}

@keyframes glowing {
   0% { background-position: 0 0; }
   50% { background-position: 400% 0; }
   100% { background-position: 0 0; }
}

and here is the HTML code:
<button class="glow-on-hover"
type="button">HOVER ME, THEN CLICK ME!
</button>

The button is from DEV Community. Button animation CSS: 75 beautiful CSS Buttons. The code to the button is credited to Kocsten. Here is a URL: https://dev.to/webdeasy/top-20-css-buttons-animations-f41

JavaFX uses the CSS language, but not HTML CSS attributes.  It also has some extensions to CSS that HTML does not use. Vice versa, there are extensions in HTML CSS that don't apply to JavaFX CSS (some of which, such as animations, are used in the CSS you provide).  The CSS attributes and features supported by JavaFX are defined in the CSS reference guide.  Styling buttons. Animating Buttons.

Note that HTML buttons and CSS will work if you place them in a WebView.

What does "It works when I copy CSS code that doesn't have any extra HTML code." mean? What exactly is working?

I always get ideas from http://fxexperience.com/2011/12/styling-fx-buttons-with-css/
